# Is it possible to update a Document Library's property column using SQL?

Tags: list, column, bulk

I'm a newbie with SharePoint so apologies if my terminology is a bit shaky. I've got a situation where the "Title" column associated with all documents in a Document Library (SharePoint 2013) needs updating:

[image]

[image]

There are ~93K documents in this library so updating them manually isn't an option.

Is it possible to locate and update this column value via SQL? I've been looking at the WSS_Content database but I can't seem to find any reference to columns in there. AllDocs has a column MetaInfo - would this contain the data in binary format?

If it's not possible to do it via SQL, what would be the easiest way to do the update? Can it be done using PowerShell?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

It is explicitly not supported to update the SharePoint databases directly! DO NOT do this!

In this situation, PowerShell is your friend. Look into an example such as those on [http://www.sharepointdiary.com](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/03/powershell-script-to-update-sharepoint-list-item.html) as a good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

lol i don't get what you want to do???? you want to change the Title column to something else?

eg... Title to HelloWorld? if it is then when your in the settings library click on "Title" should take you to the correct location (Edit Column page). Here you can change Title to anything you want ;)

> **Hint** 
>   just to note that when you change it, its only changing the display
>   text. when on the same edit page just look at the url. at the end it will say somthing like `FldEdit.aspx?List=%7BBCFA0A3A-A6D3-449C-84E0-3BC825585A00%7D&Field=Title` , the important part is the last part that contains the name " **Title** ". This doesnt change once created so any time you need to refer to this column using its **internal name** than copy it from the url otherwise just use the display value (whatever you changed it to).

do not touch microsofts SQL backend. You would lose instant support if it breaks (bad practice).

Comment: I would assume that he need to change the value of the title property for **every** item in the list, for example by adding a prefix to the current one. Since he obviously don't want to do that manually (93k + items...) he is searching for a programmatic approach.

Comment: yeah thought so, just the way he worded it sounded like he wanted to update the title field.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist yes you've got it spot on - that's exactly the case

Comment: what version of sharepoint you using?

Comment: It's SharePoint 2013